# Linux - Shell - Bash possui ou não variáveis tipo booleanas?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Tenho visto diversos materiais e tutoriais na Web dizendo que o shell do Linux não trabalha com variáveis booleanas, ou seja, com variáveis contendo os valores true ou false, e que o jeito certo de fazer isso é usando os valores 0 ou 1. Ou seja, variáveis no bash só poderiam ser dos tipos String, inteiros ou arrays.
Porém eu uso variáveis com valores true ou false, e parecem funcionar sem problemas. Exemplo:

```
#! /bin/bash

existe=false

if $existe; then
    echo "sim"
else
    echo "nao"
fi
```

Se isso me parece funcionar sem problemas, porque há tantos materiais informando que o shell não trabalha com variáveis true ou false? Será que há algum problema envolvido no uso de true ou false que eu ainda não entendi? Agradeço qualquer esclarecimento.

Comment: Experimente trocar para `existe=abc` ou `existe=ls` e veja o que acontece. Basicamente, o `false` ali é uma string (seria o mesmo que `existe="false"`), e o que acontece no `if` é explicado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21768067)

Comment: hkotsubo - Realmente a sua explicação resolveu o "mistério" na minha cabeça. Eu não havia sacado que o IF tentava converter a String pra um comando, e nem havia percebido que existem os comandos TRUE  e FALSE, tanto na pasta /BIN como também nos próprios comandos builtin do SHELL.
Entendido isso, vou aproveitar e fazer outra pergunta... mesmo entendido que TRUE e FALSE não são tipos de variáveis e sim comandos, mas já que esses comandos existem, posso usá-los nos scripts "fingindo" que eles são tipos de variáveis (como no meu exemplo)? Ou pode ter algum problema que eu ainda não previ?

Comment: @PauloLuvisoto pode usar sim, provavelmente esse é o objetivo deles existirem, já que true e false são comandos "utilitários", então provavelmente tem essa mesma intenção, usar para indicar dentro de situações, seja bash ou diretamente no terminal (e até configurar coisas como variáveis de ambiente, o que dependeria de algo mais, mas só estou "citando" as possibilidades de uso).

Comment: Guilherme Nascimento, grato!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se você executar os seguintes comandos, em terminal mesmo, vai notar o retorno deles:

Com `help true`:

Exemplo de saída:

```
[inphinit@pc ~]$ help true
true: true
    Return a successful result.

    Exit Status:
    Always succeeds.
```

Com `help false`:

```
[inphinit@pc ~]$ help false
false: false
    Return an unsuccessful result.

    Exit Status:
    Always fails.
```

Você também pode executar o `man true` e `man false` que vai ver a descrição mais completa sobre ambos.

O `exit status` é o que deixa bem claro o comportamento do comando `true` e `false` (sim, ambos são comandos).

Qualquer programa que retorna um status com sucesso vai passar em um `if` no bash:

```
resultado=foobar

if $resultado; then
    echo "sim"
else
    echo "não"
fi
```

Se o programa retornar um status de sucesso vai entrar no `if` retornando no exemplo `sim`, se o programa não existir ou retornar status de falha vai exibir o `não`

---

### Fazendo um teste com o comando `exit`

Podemos simular o resultado como sucesso ou falha usando o comando exit, por convenção comum o `0` é usado para emitir sucesso enquanto o `1` para emitir falha, então um exemplo simples que vai exibir `FALHOU`:

```
$resultado=$(exit 1)

if $resultado; then
    echo "SUCESSO"
else
    echo "FALHOU"
fi
```

Para emitir `SUCESSO` troque por:

```
$resultado=$(exit 0)
```

Você também pode fazer simular usando o comando `sh -c "<outro comando>"`, basicamente ele executará um comando a parte e retornará o status, para emitir sucesso (lembrando que o `0` é sucesso na saída de status):

```
if sh -c "exit 0"; then
...
else
...
```

Para emitir o falha (irá para o `else`):

```
if sh -c "exit 1"; then
...
else
...
```

---

### Verificando o status de saída

Em bash você pode checar o último status usando `$?`, dessa forma você pode confirmar que o true e false são comandos:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

true

echo Status do comando true: $?

false

echo Status do comando false: $?
```

Irá exibir:

```
Status do comando true: 0
Status do comando false: 1
```

Teste online em: https://ideone.com/LgF7tW